# Listview - Getview called multiple times

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` and a custom adapter. Now i have red posts about `getView()` method being called multiple times, and most of them have to do with the `wrap_content` feature of the `ListView`.

I have changed my height, so that it can be `match_parent` but still, the method is being called.

I think it has something to do with adding `TextView`s dynamically in the adapter, and i don't know how to do it, so it works properly.

If there is an alternative, i am opened to it, the only reason why i put `TextView`s is so that i can have letters written in different colors.

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View v = convertView;
        Row current = mList.get(position);

         /* if the given channel row view is not being updated*/
        if (v == null)
        {
        /* inflate layout */
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null,false);
        }

        v = setLinearLayout(v,current);

    return v;
}
```

Here is the `setLinearLayout()` method:

```
 private View setLinearLayout(View v,Row current) {

    ArrayList<Integer> winResults = current.checkNumbers(mResult,mType);
    int numbers[] = current.getNumbers();

    int N = Global.getNumberOfNumbers(mType);
    boolean FLAG_SET = false;

    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Log.d("PAVLE",""+i+" row is: "+current.getStringNumbers());
        // create a new textview
        final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(v.getContext());

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,75);
        rowTextView.setTextSize(24.0f);
        rowTextView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        rowTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        rowTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        rowTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        rowTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        if(mType == R.string.sans_topu && i == 5 && !FLAG_SET){
            i--;
            rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            rowTextView.setText("+");
            FLAG_SET = true;
        }
        else {
            // set some properties of rowTextView or something
            if (mWin == Global.WIN || mWin == Global.LOSE) {
                if (winResults.contains(numbers[i]))
                    rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                else rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if (numbers[i] < 10) {
                rowTextView.setText("0" + numbers[i]);
            } else rowTextView.setText("" + numbers[i]);
        }
        // add the textview to the linearlayout
       LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_item);
       ll.addView(rowTextView);

        // save a reference to the textview for later
        myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
    }

    final TextView prize = new TextView(v.getContext());
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,75);
    prize.setTextSize(24.0f);
    prize.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    prize.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    prize.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    prize.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    prize.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    prize.setLayoutParams(lp);

    try {
        String cash = findCorretAmmount(winResults, numbers);
        prize.setText(cash);
        mTotal.append(" "+cash);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_item);
    ll.addView(prize);

    return v;
}
```

And a little bit of XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRandomTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:text="@string/your_ticket_numbers_"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvRandomTextView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvRowList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider4"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/delete"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_share"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/done"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResultLink"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    />
```

Also worth mentioning is that `list_item2`(LinearLayout) has height of 100dp, it's fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not about textview.
The getView is always called multiple times. If you have 10 items on the screen to be shown, the getView going to be called 15 times, because the android creating views that are not on the screen. It`s good, because when the user start scrolling, it is not going to lagging.

After the user left the item, the view get`s recycle and reused by the adapter. Lets say, you have a list with 10000000 item, but you have 5 item on the screen at all time. In this case - to save power, and improve performance - the android going to create 10 list item, and this 10 item is going to recylce and refresh by content.

**ViewHolder pattern**
Please read this and use this patter to improve your code performance:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

**Google about** ListView:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

**Tutorials**:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/

Comment: It`s my pleasure, take your time. If my links was useful , don`t hesitate to accept and ask more :)